# Readonly field in workflow openerp

Tags: odoo

I try to make all fields read only in state win and lost but it doesn't work.

```html
<record id="phieuxuatform" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Phiếu xuất</field>
  <field name="model">tt_phieuxuat</field> 
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <header>
        <button name="getdonhang" string="Lấy sản phẩm từ đơn hàng" type="object" states="new"/>
        <button name="mymod_negotiation" string="Xem xét" states="new" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" confirm="Vui lòng xem xét kĩ vì sau bước này bạn không được quyền chỉnh sửa nữa?"/>
        <button name="mymod_won" string="Đồng ý" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
        <button name="mymod_lost" string="Không đồng ý" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
        <field  name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="new,negotiation,won,lost"/>
      </header>
      <sheet>
        <separator string ="Thông tin"/>
        <group col="2">
          <field name="name" on_change="getname()" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
          <field name="ten" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
          <field name="nam" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
          <field name="ngay" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
          <field name="donhang" domain="[('tinhtrang','=','ht')]" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
        </group>
        <field name="danhsach" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',['won','lost'])]}"/>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<record id="phieuxuatform" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Phiếu xuất</field>
    <field name="model">tt_phieuxuat</field> 
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <header>
        <button name="getdonhang" string="Lấy sản phẩm từ đơn hàng" type="object" states="new"/>
        <button name="mymod_negotiation" string="Xem xét" states="new" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" confirm="Vui lòng xem xét kĩ vì sau bước này bạn không được quyền chỉnh sửa nữa?"/>
        <button name="mymod_won" string="Đồng ý" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
        <button name="mymod_lost" string="Không đồng ý" states="negotiation" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
        <field  name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="new,negotiation,won,lost"/>
      </header>
      <sheet>
        <separator string ="Thông tin"/>
        <group col="2">
          <field name="name" on_change="getname()" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
          <field name="ten" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
          <field name="nam" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
          <field name="ngay" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
          <field name="donhang" domain="[('tinhtrang','=','ht')]" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
        </group>
        <field name="danhsach" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in',('won','lost'))]}"/>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```